# How can I bypass focus assist's alarm setting for toast messages?

Tags: xml, windows, winforms, powershell, toast

I have created a custom toast message in Windows 10 that I need to display even when the focus assist setting is set to 'Alarms only'. It appears that with a windows update, the 'Alarms only' setting is set by default when applications go to full screen, when duplicating displays, or playing games. I need a way to either bypass the 'Alarms only' setting, or disable focus assist through a script.

I have attempted to change the setting in group policy as seen here:
[Manage Focus Assist on Windows 10](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/06/04/manage-focus-assist-on-windows-10/)

as well as through the registry as seen here:
[How to Change Windows 10 Quiet Hours (Focus Assist) Automatic Rules](https://appuals.com/how-to-change-windows-10-quiet-hours-focus-assist-automatic-rules/)

Neither of these methods appear to have an affect. Below is my Powershell script that is used to create the toast message:

```
param(
[String] $Msg1,
[String] $Logo1
)
function test
{
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
    [void][Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]

$App_ID = 'windows.immersivecontrolpanel_cw5n1h2txyewy!microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel'

$template = @"
<toast scenario="alarm">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text id="1">$("$Msg1")</text>
            <image placement="appLogoOverride" src="$Logo1"/>
        </binding>
    </visual>
</toast>
"@
$xml = New-Object Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument
$xml.LoadXml($template)
$test = New-Object Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification $xml
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($APP_ID).Show($test)
}

if ($Msg1) {test}
```

The toast message should display by running the script passing the -Msg1 'This is a test' to it. Instead, it does not display, and can only be seen in the action center.

Has anybody been able to display a toast notification regardless of the focus assist (quiet hours) setting? Or does anybody know a method to disable focus assist through a script that appears to work (This needs to be done without user interaction)?